# If $f$ is increasing, show that $\omega_f(a) = f(a+) - f(a-)$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is increasing, show that  $\omega_f(a) = f(a+) - f(a-)$.

$\omega_f(a) = \inf\limits_{I open, a\in I} \omega(f;I) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \omega(f;(a-h,a+h))$

where,  $\omega(f;I) = \sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|: x,y \in I\}$

My attempt :

Using the sequential argument I have been able to prove that if f is an increasing function then,at any point $x_0$ in the domain

$$f(x_0^+) = \inf\limits_{x>x_0} f(x)$$ and

$$f(x_o^-) = \sup\limits_{x<x_0} f(x)$$

I am not able to proceed further and conclude the result.

Comment: Note $\omega(f; (a-h,a+h)) = f(a+h) - f(a-h)$.

Comment: @JohnMa I would say $\cdots\leq\cdots$ instead of $\cdots=\cdots$

Comment: @JohnMa...thanks for the hint, but f does not attain these values in the open interval (a-h, a+h), so how can we write the abv expression ?

Comment: Try to compare with the interval $(a-h/2, a+h/2)$. @spaceman_spiff